# How can I convert a uint128_t to a string?

Tags: smart-contract

I am using a `uint128_t` as an id type for a contract I am working on.  For a certain check, I need to convert this variable to a `string` so I can check for it in another table (whose type cannot be changed).  How can I convert the `uint128_t` variable to a string without having to`#include "sstream"`, which is warned against by the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution but I used a little parser, which is closely connected to the eosio account name conversion from GitHub:

```
static const char* charmap = "0123456789";


std::string uint128ToString(const uint128_t& value)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve( 40 ); // max. 40 digits possible ( uint64_t has 20) 
    uint128_t helper = value;

    do {
        result += charmap[ helper % 10 ];
        helper /= 10;
    } while ( helper );
    std::reverse( result.begin(), result.end() );
    return result;
}
```

It will divide by 10 and use the charmap to identify the number representation to use.

Comment: This was the approach I ended up taking.  It seems to work well.